# Android Studio 3 canary & Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Has anyone got the message "Kotlin not Configured"

I'm sure I missed something, but for the most part I downloaded it, and just had it import my existing 2.x settings. I tried a simply copy/paste from a java class to a new Kotlin file, and that's where I'm at.

Here is my current top level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter {
            url = "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
        maven {
            url = "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter {
            url = "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
        maven {
            url = "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

And then at the top of my module build file I have these two lines

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

The current error is "Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found"

Comment: Did you properly setup the gradle build, gradle plugin and kotlin plugin? If you aren't sure with those, you may need to show us someting about them so we can actually locate down the problem instead of making a wild guess.

Comment: I added a *.kt file
I then got the message up top saying Kotlin not configured.
I think clicked on the Configure -> Android With Gradle
I think selected All Modules with Kotlin Files -> Ok
I hit "Sync now" because Gradle had changed

And now it appears my Gradle file is broken because I get 


Error:(2, 0) Extension with name 'android' does not exist. 

I think the root cause is the following line in mobile/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

Comment: Would it make a difference that my project uses NDK, and I'm currently using the experimental gradle (0.9.2).  Is it just not possible since I need the experimental for NDK?

Comment: @GREnvoy seems to be not possible. At least I'm not finding any hints at how this could be done. We need something like `kotlin-android-experimental` or something to use with the `gradle-experimental` plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a Kotlin dependency in the `dependencies` block:

```
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: I added the line below and now get "Gradle YourModule project refresh failed, Error: Cause compileSdkVersion is not specified"

        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.2-4'

Answer (score 1):

That message has appeared in previous versions of Android Studio (before v.3.0) when Kotlin library was not among class paths in the gradle script.

Probably, when importing your project that had no Kotlin, you've got overlapping with previous settings that results in the fact that Kotlin has not been found.

Try to create a project from scratch, insert your Java code and convert it into Kotlin (Code > Convert Java File to Kotlin File)

[image: Java -> Kotlin file converter]

Answer (score 0):

Usually the automatic configurator "just works", but take a look at whta it was trying to do: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#targeting-android

Comment: I tried to follow these steps, but now get plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found

Comment: I added some of my config values to the post above

Comment: I can get past the Kotlin not configured, but get errors with Gradle 3.5 and configured  in my gradle-wrapper.properties and 2.3.2 in my build.gradle, I now get the error

buildToolsVersion is not specified.  Is this an issue with me having NDK and needing the experimental version?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I solved it pretty simple: Modify build.gradle to force a gradle sync.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.
Just go to Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure kotlin in project.
In the window that appears, click on Android with gradle.
Let the project sync and you are good to go.